# Sequelize many-to-many relation and one-to-many in intermediate table

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Hi have a table `Users` with many to many relation to `Groups` through `UsersGroups`. `UsersGroups` has a FK to `UsersGroupsRoles`:

[image]

Users:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Users = sequelize.define(
        'Users',
        {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.UUID,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
                primaryKey: true,
            },

            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
            },
        },
        {}
    );
    Users.associate = function(models) {
        Users.belongsToMany(models.Groups, { through: models.UsersGroups });
    };

    return Users;
};
```

Groups:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Groups = sequelize.define(
        'Groups',
        {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },

            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
            },
        },
        {}
    );

    Groups.associate = function(models) {
        Groups.belongsToMany(models.Users, { through: models.UsersGroups });
    };

    return Groups;
};
```

UsersGroups:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const UsersGroups = sequelize.define(
        'UsersGroups',
        {
            order: {
                allowNull: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                defaultValue: 10000,
            },
        },
        {}
    );
    UsersGroups.associate = function(models) {
        UsersGroups.belongsTo(models.UsersGroupsRoles, { as: 'UsersGroupsRoles', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
    };

    return UsersGroups;
};
```

UsersGroupsRoles:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const UsersGroupsRoles = sequelize.define(
        'UsersGroupsRoles',
        {
            id: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },

            role: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
            },
        },
        {}
    );

    UsersGroupsRoles.associate = function(models) {
        UsersGroupsRoles.hasMany(models.UsersGroups, { as: 'UsersGroupsRoles', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
    };

    return UsersGroupsRoles;
};
```

Now I want to query Users and UsersGroups, and get the `UsersGroupsRoles`:

```
models.Groups.findAll({
    attributes: {
        exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt'],
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Users,
            attributes: {
                exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'email', 'password'],
            },
            through: {
                include: [
                    {
                        model: models.UsersGroupsRoles,
                        as: 'UsersGroupsRoles',
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

But the query fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. I suppose it is because the `include` clause inside `through`, but then, what is the correct way to include a one-to-many association in an intermediate table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about try this?

```
try {
    let groups = await models.Groups.findAll({
      attributes: {
          exclude: ['id','createdAt', 'updatedAt'],
      }
    })

    const userGroupsPromises = groups.map(group => {
      return models.UsersGroups.findAll({
        where: {
          groupId: group.id
        },
        include: [{
          model: models.User,
          attributes: {
            exclude: ['createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'email', 'password'],
        }
        }, {
          model: models.UsersGroupsRoles,
        }]
      })
    })

    const userGroupsPromiseResult = await Promise.all(userGroupsPromises)

    groups = groups.map((group, index) => {
      const _group = group.get()
      _group.UserGroups = userGroupsPromiseResult[index]

      return _group
    })

    console.log(groups)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yes, using promises would be an option. But I would like my API to look as simple as possible, so I would like to find the «Sequelize» way to do it :)

Comment: Then, what about use `belongTo`, `hasMany` instead of `belongToMany`? I think You can't include user data if you use `belongToMany`

Comment: Yes, there should be a way to do it as you say, I was thinking about it. But I can't believe that Sequelize doesn't support `belongTo` associations on intermediate tables created with `belongToMany` out of the box :O

Comment: I had same issues with you. But I just use promises. I coundn't find the best way.

Comment: I use promises for POST requests, as they allow me to introduce data in complex structures. But for GET it should be easy! I did what you said, describing all the relations as one-to-many with `belongTo` and `hasMany` instead of using many-to-many. It works, and the code is easy to write and read, maybe better than `belongsTo`! I think you should add it as an answer… :)